# How it is possible to know if an option of dropdown menu is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with `radiobox`, `input` (`type='text`' or `type='checkbox'`), `textarea`... dropdown menu (`select`).. and I want to show a different div depending on how much input are filled/checked. I wrote this for the input (`type='text'`) selecting input id by id but how it is possible do the same thing for `select` and `textarea`

```
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {

$("input[id*='ebit'], input[id*='nome_progetto'], input[id*='posizione_netta'], input[id*='descrizione'], input[id*='stato_transazione']").blur(function() {
   var counter=0;
    $("input[id*='ebit'], input[id*='posizione_netta']").each(function(ind, val){
        if($(val).val().trim()!==""){
            counter=counter+2;
        }
    });
     $("input[id*='nome_progetto'], input[id*='descrizione']").each(function(ind, val){
        if($(val).val().trim()!==""){
            counter++;
        }
    });

     $("input[id*='stato_transazione']").each(function(ind, val){
        if($(val).val().trim()!==""){
            counter++;
        }
    });


    $("#green_0, #green_1, #green_2, #green_3, #green_4, #green_5, #green_6, #green_7, #green_8, #green_9, #green_10, #green_11, #green_12, #green_13, #green_14, #green_15").hide();

    $("#green_"+counter).show(); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your textarea and select have ids, you can refer to their values like

select:

```
$("#selectId").val();
```

textarea:

```
$("#textAreaId").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

have a option

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select Option</option>
```

and use

```
if($("#selectId").val()!=='')
 counter++;
```

And for textboxes you can use

```
if($("#textAreaId").val()!=='')
    counter++;
```

Comment: this does not work, i have to add something at the signature of the function? such as option[id*='myid'] ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery

```
$('option:selected').text()
```

Gives you the selected option text.

```
$('option:selected').val()
```

Gives you selected option value

```
$('#myselect option:selected').val()
```

If you have multiple select boxes. Where *myselect* is your select ID

Comment: I want this function [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yaw5zaz2/)  but selecting all id by id and not by type

Comment: Give it some effort on your own. You should not expect to get custom code from SO